# Find bit location in groovy and put into an list

Tags: groovy

The groovy script needs to find the x location of string1 and put them into a list. The final output will be like
finaList=[[2,3],[5]]

The following scripts are created by me, but it doesn't work

```
checkStr='01xx0x1'
i=0
tempaList=[]
finalList=[]

while (i<checkStr.length()){
    if(checkStr[i]=='x'){
        tempaList.add(i)
    }else if(tempaList.length()>1){
        finalList.add([tempaList[0],tempaList[-1]])
        tempaList=[]
    }else if (tempaList.length()==1){
        finaList.add([tempaList])
        tempaList=[]
    }
    i=i+1
}
println finaList
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your desired result of a list of lists. If, as you stated, your only goal is to find all indexes that 'x' is at, you can use:

```
def str ='01xx0x'
str.findIndexValues { it == 'x' } // result -> [2, 3, 5]
```

If you do want to maintain your groupings, you need to make sure you handle the case of your last character being an 'x'. Your current code will not handle instances where `tempaList` has a value but the loop has finished iterating over the string.

```
def checkStr = '01xx0x1'
def temp = []
def end = []

for (int i=0; i < checkStr.size(); i++) {
    if (checkStr[i] == 'x') {
        temp << i
    } else if (temp.size()) {
        // temp has size (indexes) and we've hit a non-'x' char
        end << temp
        temp = []
    }
 } 

// If the final char was an x (or multiple x's), handle that here 
if (temp) {
    end << temp
}

println end // result -> [[2, 3], [5]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
checkStr='01xx0x1'
i=0
tempaList=[]
finalList=[]

while(i<checkStr.length()){
    if(checkStr[i]=="x"){
       // println i
        tempaList.add(i)
    }else if (tempaList.size()>1){
        finalList.add([tempaList[0],tempaList[-1]])
        tempaList=[]
    }else if (tempaList.size()==1){
        finalList.add(tempaList)
        tempaList=[]
    }
    i=i+1
}

println finalList
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).